# Simple Concept behind port forward in NAT network

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I think most of the household internet uses the NAT network. That is within the household, every device is having a unique private IPv4. Then many households are sharing one public IPv4. Suppose I set up a web server on local port 80 and then set the port forward from the public IPv4 port 80 to my local device. That means my web server is occupying the public IPv4's port 80 and other households cannot port-forward the public IPv4 port 80 to their local device? Is my understanding correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then many households are sharing one public IPv4.

This is called "Carrier Grade NAT" (CGNAT) and is different from normal NAT.  In normal NAT, *each* household gets 1 public IP.  In CGNAT, multiple households will be behind 1 public IP.

In a normal NAT situation, you can setup port forwarding rules on your router, and your router will follow them - it can do this because there's no further NAT between you and the carrier.

In a CGNAT situation, your ISP has to setup port forwarding rules on their carrier-grade router to get what you want to do to work (and they probably won't--they may sell you a static IP though).  You can setup port forwarding on your own router but nothing's going to happen because the ISPs NAT is in front of you.

Comment: Hi Lawrence, Thanks for your answer. I am wondering what method I could use to confirm the type of internet I am using (NAT or CGNAT)? Should I contact my ISP to confirm that?

Comment: Your ISP should definitely be able to tell you.  Additionally - you can log into the router your ISP gives you and check its WAN interface IP.  If the WAN IP starts with 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, or 172.16.x.x-172.13.x.x then you're probably behind CGNAT.  You can also try doing a `tracert google.com` from a command line and if the 2nd hop is one of those, that's also a sign of CGNAT.